# Numbers wrong on StackExchange.com All Sites tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com

[image]

For some reason, Stack Overflow, The Workplace, Computer Science, and Libraries and Information Science started showing up as having 0 questions, 0 answers, NaN% answered with 0 users in the [StackExchange.com/sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) page.

Comment: Aw you posted just before I did.

Comment: Well, at least we have answered all questions!

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII yes, but we divided by zero

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We had some very unexpected behavior from upgrading the JSON serializer which wasn't actually deployed until APIv2 was built today...for a few minutes it was throwing some very unfriendly JSON with surprise properties.

That's been corrected (reverted) and the cache has expired on stackexchange.com, so all should be well now.

Comment: Is [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136383/whats-up-with-the-0-accounts) caused by the same unexpected behavior?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd - nope, that was during a backfill today to sync things up...though the not handling that gracefully on SE.com (now that the accounts tab is there only) wasn't on the radar...it's slated for a fix now