# NaN answered, aka EEEEEEEEEK! Don't you like us any more?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stackexchange.com

MSO, Stack Apps, Robotics, Expression Engine Answers, Sustainable Living and Network Engineering all have 0 questions, 0 answers and 0 users on [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questions).

[image]

Comment: And the Great Close Update eats something else! I'm sure they'll fix it up in no time.

Comment: Also: apparently this [happened a year ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136299/numbers-wrong-on-stackexchange-com-all-sites-tab?rq=1) and was marked status-completed.

Comment: Caching. It's always cashing. :)

Comment: It's a strange few numbers to cache @ShaWizDowArd :-). I've cleared mine, it's almost an hour and I've visited in incognito mode... no change.

Comment: server cache, nothing we can do as mortal users.

Comment: At this rate, we've been asking -28.6 questions per day for the last 4 years on MSO! Yay!

Comment: You could say a "math overflow" might be responsible. Hohohoho.

Comment: *NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN* BAT-MAN!

Comment: maybe, a super-net-NaNny will be needed to help out?

Comment: @ShaWizDow I too like cashing. Especially checks.

Comment: Looks like a glitch in the matrix. Sorted out now, though no one here did anything...